# Can we show the nested objects in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I am adding a .NET type to PowerShell session using `Add-Type` and then creating object of that type using `New-Object`. This is done as follows:

```powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName OuterObj
$a = New-Object OuterObj
```

Object of type `OuterObj` is successfully created. Now .NET type `$a` has a field named `innerObj` which is object of another .NET type `innerObject`. So I add `innerObject` .NET type and create an instance using `New-Object`:

```powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName innerObject
$b = New-Object innerObject
```

Object of type `innerObject` is also successfully created. Now I do as follows:

```powershell
$a.innerObj = $b
```

Now when I print `$a`, it shows something like this:

```powershell
innerObj : innerObject
```

Thus it does not display the contents of `innerObject` by default. When I go and explore, `innerObj` has the fields. I know PowerShell does not show the nested objects by default but instead just shows their types, but is there a way I can specify that what level of nesting of objects PowerShell should show by default? Is there something to specify to show 1 or 2 levels of nested objects?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If this is for a custom type which you will use a lot, you might want to look into creating a custom `ps1xml` file for your type (start by reading `Get-Help about_types.ps1xml`). Otherwise, you could use my answer below.

Comment: Yes I am ready to create a custom ps1xml file but the issue is that I am unable to find how to do it in ps1xml file also. I want the output to be somethings like this(in list format) : Name:outerName \n InnerThingy:{Name:innerName, Description:innerDescription, myChild:InnerInnerType}. Thus I would like to display the objects with one level of nesting in this manner. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any built-in functionality for this, but it is pretty easy to create a function which should get you where you want to go. Here's an example:

```
function ConvertTo-NestedPropertyHash
{
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [object[]]$InputObject
    ,
        [string[]]$ExpandProperty
    )
    PROCESS 
    {
        foreach($item in $InputObject)
        {
            $hash = @{}
            $processStack = New-Object System.Collections.Stack
            $processStack.Push(@{ Item = $item})
            while($processStack.Count -gt 0)
            {
                $current = $processStack.Pop()
                $prefix = $current.Prefix
                $object = $current.Item
                foreach($property in $object | gm | where membertype -eq "Property")
                {
                    if ($Prefix)
                    {
                        $propertyPath = "$Prefix.$($property.Name)"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $propertyPath = $Property.Name
                    }
                    $propertyValue = $object."$($property.Name)"
                    if ($ExpandProperty -contains $propertyPath)
                    {
                        $processStack.Push(@{ 
                            Prefix = $propertyPath
                            Item = $propertyValue
                        })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $hash.Add($propertyPath, $propertyValue)
                    }
                }
            }
            Write-Output $hash
        }
    }
}
```

The above function lets you specify properties (with a dot-notation for subproperties) which you want expanded. So given the following types:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
public class InnerInnerType
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
public class InnerType
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
    public InnerInnerType MyChild{get;set;}
}
public class OuterType
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public InnerType InnerThingy {get;set;}
}
"@
```

And the following objects created:

```
$outer = New-Object OuterType
$inner = New-Object InnerType
$childToInner = New-OBject InnerInnerType
$outer.Name = "outer name"
$inner.Name = "inner name"
$inner.Description = "inner description"
$childToInner.Name = "inner inner thingy"
$outer.innerthingy = $inner
$inner.MyChild = $childToInner
```

You could use the function without asking it to expand any properties, like so:

```
$outer | ConvertTo-NestedPropertyHash
```

Which would yield the following output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           outer name
InnerThingy                    InnerType
```

Or you could ask it to expand the `InnerThingy` property:

```
$outer | ConvertTo-NestedPropertyHash -ExpandProperty InnerThingy
```

Which yields:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
InnerThingy.MyChild            InnerInnerType
Name                           outer name
InnerThingy.Description        inner description
InnerThingy.Name               inner name
```

Or you could also specify nested properties using dot-notation (current implementation of the function requires that you expand a property to be able to expand sub-properties from that property, so you'd need to do `-ExpandProperty InnerThingy, "InnerThingy.MyChild"` if you want to expand the `MyChild` nested property), like the following:

```
$outer | ConvertTo-NestedPropertyHash -ExpandProperty InnerThingy, "InnerThingy.MyChild"
```

Which yields:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           outer name
InnerThingy.Description        inner description
InnerThingy.MyChild.Name       inner inner thingy
InnerThingy.Name               inner name
```